# How to get part of deep link in activity?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have deep link which redirects user to activity. Deep link looks like "https://example.com/login/userId". Is there any way I can get this userId in activity?

UPD. It seems I didn't explain my question clearly. User clicks on link in his email and opens app with intent. And in this activity i need to get part deep link which was redirected him to this activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just split the String?
In your case, just split it as

```
mylink.split("/")[4];
```

If it is a url, `toString()` it.

Then pass it to whatever Activity using an Extra.

Now that you have updated it, send the url you recieved in your current Activity, then create the Intent for the Activity you're about to launch, then send the url as a String and pass i to the Intent as a StringExtra, and then upon opening of the other Activity, get the link string via. `getIntent().getStringExtra();`. Then proceed to split.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not what i am looking for. I update my question, please, check it.

Comment: You have to *pass* values from one Activity to the other. You do this with the help of **Extras** or **Bundles**.

Comment: For more info regarding this, please refer to: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles

Comment: If you app is different and not a same app Activity, then you refer to: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Uri` to get the userId

```
URI uri = new URI("https://example.com/login/userId");
String path = uri.getPath();
String userId = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: It seems I didn't explain my question clearly. User clicks on link in his email and opens app with intent. And in this activity i need to get part deep link which was redirected him to this activity.